# LINQ to Entities returns empty list but it's SQL equivalent returns results

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

I'm sure this is something fairly common... I'm joining two entities with a mapping table and attempting to load back all relationships.

```
        public IEnumerable<Clinic> ClientClinics(Guid clientId)
        {
            var clinics =
                from c in _appDbContext.Clinics
                join ccm in _appDbContext.ClientClinicMappings on c.ClinicId equals ccm.ClinicId
                join cli in _appDbContext.Clients on ccm.ClientId equals cli.ClientId
                where cli.ClientId == clientId && !c.DeletedAt.HasValue
                select c;

            return clinics.ToList();
        }
```

I'm getting no results when I should be... I turned on the db logging and here's the generated SQL:

```
SELECT [c].[ClinicId], [c].[Address], [c].[City], [c].[CreatedAt], [c].[CreatedBy], [c].[DeletedAt], [c].[DeletedBy], [c].[ModifiedAt], [c].[ModifiedBy], [c].[Name], [c].[Phone], [c].[State], [c].[Zip]
FROM [Clinic] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [ClientClinicMapping] AS [ccm] ON [c].[ClinicId] = [ccm].[ClinicId]
INNER JOIN [Client] AS [cli] ON [ccm].[ClientId] = [cli].[ClientId]
WHERE ([cli].[ClientId] = @__clientId_0) AND [c].[DeletedAt] IS NULL
```

When I paste in my GUID that I'm searching with, I'm able to get results from SQL.

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions to where I should be looking or what to be trying?

Comment: i would suggest to avoid HasValue. try .GetValueOrDefault() or == null. there were an issue with that extention IMHO.

Comment: Not enough info in question. My guess is wrong connection string. Also, never save the DbContext as a field - always create in a using clause (you can inject the constructor factory for this).

Comment: I think  `@__clientId_0` has to be wrong are you sure you passing in something that is converted correctly to a GUI?  If you have a string I doubt it will work.

Comment: @PowerMouse this seemed to be the issue, I think I can get away with just removing the null check here anyways. Thanks!